# How can i properly style PHP mailed text from web form?

Tags: php, html, css, email, contact-form

I have this web contact page i am working on, but when sending emails, it arrives in plain text but i would like to add a background and an organization logo on top and style the text to fit the website's flat design. I been having trouble getting around this so i am here as a last resort.

Anyone have a proper way of accomplishing this ?

Here is a screenshot of how i am trying to accomplish this when received thru an email. (The organization needs to see this in their mailbox either on iPhone or mac email client.)
[image]

Here is the basic code i have at the moment which spits out the plain text:

```
<?php


 $field_name = $_POST['name'];
 $field_email = $_POST['email'];
 $field_message = $_POST['message'];

 header("Location: contact-thanks.php"); ## important redirect page


 $mail_to = 'DESIGNATED_EMAIL'; ## Organization's receiving email
 $subject = 'Message from an a Visitor '.$field_name;

 $body_message = '<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
       <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
       </head>

  <body style="margin:0px; padding:0px; background:#f7f7f7;">
  <div style="display:block; margin:auto; width:750px;background:#2C3E50; border-bottom: solid 2px #2C3E50;">
  <div style="display:block; width:750px; margin:auto;">
  <span style="color:#fff;padding:5px 10px;display:block;font-size:22px;">From: Johny,</span>
  </div>

  </div>
  <div style="width:750px; margin: auto; background:#fff; min-height: 100px;">
  <div style="text-align: left;display: block;width: 500px;padding: 50px; padding-bottom:30px;font-size: 14px;color: #666; margin:auto;">
  <div style="color:inherit;display:block;width:100%;margin:10px 0;line-height:24px;font-size:18px;color:#333">Hi,</div>
  <div style="color:inherit;display:block;width:100%;margin:10px 0;line-height:24px">Thank you for visiting us..<span style="color:#111;font-weight:600;display:block;">This is an example that how we formatted our email in php.</span>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div style="border-top:solid 1px #ddd; text-align:left;font-size:14px;color:#888;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:2px;padding-left:10px;">&copy; exampleOrganization.org</div>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>';

  $body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
  $body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
  $body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

  $headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
  $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

  $mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

  if ($mail_status) 
  { 
     echo "Message was sent";   
  }
  else { 
       echo "ERROR";
  }
  ?>
```

The `$body_message;` variable basically holds the entire screenshot and i figured if this would work, but i wouldn't know how to then make the three variables `$field_name;`, `$field_email` and `$field_message` write the content onto the `$body_message;` variable

Anyone can shed me some light to accomplish this last task?

Answer (score 1):

This is the format I usually use

```
$to = 'email@email.com';
$subject = 'New email!';
$from = "Your Website Name";
$message = '<html><h1>HTML formatted message in here</h1> </html>';

$headers = "From: $from\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a mailer class like this one https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: I'll try it, although it seems a bit tedious fitting this in, I did a small test earlier today but it never even sent a test email to see if it works

Comment: Sending HTML emails can be a real pain, different email reeaders give you different results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Take the content type and MIME-Version to `$headers`:

```
 $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
 $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";

 mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);
```

It works for me :) for more see [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: Awesome, I wil try this once i am back to my workplace.

Answer (score 0):

To send HTML email from PHP's `mail` function you need to specify additional headers, namely `MIME-Version, Content-Type and charset`.

Here's a [solid example](http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/) for you to follow. You might be better off using the [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) class as previously mentioned, as it abstracts much of the finer details.

Answer (score 0):

I've created two separate websites now, one for myself, and one for a *client?*. Both times I've gone with sending emails using [PHP mailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), as it's a lot easier to use than the built in mail in PHP.

It's really easy to set up:

```
$emailTo = $_POST['email']; //Users Email
$name = $_POST['name']; //Users name
$subject = "Welcome to the site new user!";
$message = "
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Website.com</title>
    <head>
    <body>
      <p>Hey " . $emailTo . ", thank you for visiting this site!
    </body>
  </html>
";

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->From = 'support@website.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Super Cool Website';
$mail->addAddress($emailTo,$name);
$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $message;
$mail->AltBody = str_tags($message);

if ( $mail->send() ) {
  echo "Your email was sent!";
} else {
  echo "Your email failed to send";
}
```

Comment: Hey this looks promising, I have to test every single one of them until i get the one that works, Where you able to add some images to styles?

Comment: Yes, you can add images into your message, but make sure to refer back to them by the full URL ``http://website.com/images/image.png`` rather than the usual ``/images/image.png``, as once the email is sent to the user, there is no /images/ directory on the users client.

Comment: One more question, just by reading over the code on your example, is this more of an email sent from the web admin to a user? The type of email i am trying to accomplish is the user goes into the contact form where he Puts his name, Email and Message and is then sent to the Admin's email where it is displayed in HTML and with some images

Comment: If you're just looking to have a contact submission form the mail() function probably isn't what you're looking for. You can either stick with the mail form and just set to ``$mailTo = 'admin@website.com';``, or set up a way to save your form to a SQL table.